# Using HDMI port as network protocol interface?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, parallel-processing, protocols

I was wondering if it's possible to use the 10.2 Gb/s HDMI port on several computers as a backbone networking interface for a home made cluster?

Is there some kind of HDMI switch? Can HDMI transport arbitrary data? Can you access the HDMI port in *nix as a device like eth0 and pipe to it? Can the HDMI port on the computers receive data, or is it outgoing only (graphics card -> display)?

This would be very cool.

If it doesn't exist, what would be the logistics of implementing this?

Comment: This is more like a ServerFault question

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm "generally" new to asking questions on the stackexchange network. Would it better received there? (I don't understand the downvotes)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close as off-topic. Yes, it would be better received there. Stack Overflow is about coding. Server Fault is about professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration, and Super User is about general computing hardware and software. This could go to either site, but I'd lean toward Server Fault.

Comment: Super User discussion from the same time: http://superuser.com/questions/640564/using-hdmi-port-as-network-protocol-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, newer versions of HDMI can support an "Ethernet channel", which functions as a regular network connection. However, I have not been able to find any graphics cards with this feature. If your graphics card supports this, it may have the letters `HEC` beside the HDMI port.
Additionally, the Ethernet channel is limited to 100 Mbit/s, so it is not the fastest option available.

I did find some HDMI switches, made by [Wiretek](http://www.wiretek.com.cn/).

HDMI also supports an auxiliary channel, which is mainly used for carrying control signals between devices. Though it is slower than the Ethernet channel.

Comment: Do think data blocks could be encoded to a digital video signal and decoded on the receiving end?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, though I think the encoding and decoding might slow it down. You would also need a graphics card supporting input or video capture.

Answer (score 2):

It's theoretically possible, but the hardware doesn't exist.  Another consideration is that your link would be very highly asymmetric (like ADSL):  Around 8.16 Gbit/s downstream (there's some overhead), and only 100Mbit/s upstream (through the Ethernet Channel).

At a low level, HDMI uses the same protocol as DVI to transmit video data, a signalling protocol called [TMDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_Minimized_Differential_Signaling).  Theoretically, you could take your data in 24-bit chunks, encode them into three 8-bit channels (representing Red, Green and Blue) and throw this across the three TMDS channels, and combine them back together at the receiving end.  You'd also need circuitry to negotiate a high bandwidth channel by setting a high resolution and refresh rate over the control channel.  More details about the architecture of HDMI are [here](http://apachetechnology.in/KC/Multimedia/PDFs/HDMI_HDMI%20Summary.pdf).

The hardware to do this would be pretty complicated (read: expensive to make).  No off-the-shell hardware exists to do this for a number of reasons:  It's a use that's not officially supported by the HDMI consortium, so they couldn't even use the HDMI logo on their product, and there's likely a lot of patents that would need licensing anyway.

In the end, it's probably cheaper (and easier!) for you to just shell out for a few fibre cards and some cabling that's designed to do what you actually need.

Comment: Since HDMI 1.4 (5 years before this answer) HDMI supports Ethernet natively as part of the HEC spec. Devices that bridge to 100baseT Ethernet do exist. Some HDBaseT adapters also have Ethernet (not just the cat5 8pc8 used for the HDBaseT itself) switches.